# A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer

Tags: hyper-v

### Short Version

Trying to connect to a Hyper-V virtual machine using **vmconnect.exe**, i get the error:

[image]

> A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer. For assistance, contact your system administrator.

The **vmconnect** program comes with Hyper-V, and is located in:

> `C:\Program Files\Hyper-V\vmconnect.exe`

We all know it's because of some new **Group Policy**, and Microsoft's *Broken By Default* rule.

But **what** group policy - so i may fix it?

### Research Effort

- i tried clicking <kbd>Connect</kbd> again; same result
- ["A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer" FIX*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/961c2dd6-c34a-4b17-a10f-a3afdd9db3f0/quota-connection-will-not-be-made-because-credentials-may-not-be-sent-to-the-remote-computerquot?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv)
- [VM Viewer cannot open console: "A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e851524d-8f2c-4e56-963d-15fbe483e09d/vm-viewer-cannot-open-console-a-connection-will-not-be-made-because-credentials-may-not-be-sent-to?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv)
- [Windows 7: vmconnect.exe faiils with - A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e783d2d6-d74d-4429-9a8a-a6085ad20dc5/windows-7-vmconnectexe-faiils-with-a-connection-will-not-be-made-because-credentials-may-not-be?forum=winserverhyperv)
- [Cannot connect to Guest OS after RC0 to RC1 update](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/ce6a9d04-45bf-4d77-869e-bbf784cbefd1/cannot-connect-to-guest-os-after-rc0-to-rc1-update?forum=winserverhyperv&forum=winserverhyperv)
- [vmconnect.exe fails with - A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84a92b5b-6e74-47cb-9f39-097e396e758a/vmconnectexe-fails-with-a-connection-will-not-be-made-because-credentials-may-not-be-sent-to-the?forum=winserverhyperv)
- [Error: A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer](https://support.s-code.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/55/8/error-a-connection-will-not-be-made-because-credentials-may-not-be-sent-to-the-remote-computer)
- [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954357](https://archive.ph/5CUZ1)
- [Windows 10: A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer.](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/a-connection-will-not-be-made-because-credentials-may-not-be-sent-to-the-remote-computer.134097/)

Comment: and the event log?

Comment: I scrolled through about 43 different logs before giving up (e.g. Application, Security, Setup, System, AppV-Admin, AppV-Operational, AppV-Virtual Applications, User Expereience Virtualization-Agent Drivers-Operational, ...  Any specifiec event log you were suggesting?

Comment: VMConnect.exe <ServerName> <VMName> /edit could maybe help else try /?